# min-max scaling of dataframe in iPython

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, normalization, jupyter-notebook

Im new in Python. I have dataframe and I want do min-max(0-1) scaling in every column (every attr). I found method MinMaxScaller but I dont know how to use it with dataframe.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

def sci_minmax(X):
    minmax_scale = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1), copy=True)
    return minmax_scale.fit_transform(X)

data_normalized = sci_minmax(data)
data_variance=data_normalized.var()
data_variance.head(10)
```

The error is 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'head'. I need the return type dataframe

Answer (score 0):

There is no `head` method in `scipy`/`numpy`.

If you want a `pandas.DataFrame`, you'll have to call the constructor.

Any chance you mean to look at the first 10 records with `head`?

You can do this easily with numpy, too.

To select the first 10 records of an array, the python syntax is `array[:10]`. With `numpy` matrixes, you will want to specify rows and columns: `array[:10,]` or `array[,:10]`

Comment: In the end I did it my way: data_norm = (data - data.min()) / (data.max() - data.min())

Comment: Be careful to distinguish whether you want per-row, per-column or per-frame normalization. The most common probably is per-column; I guess your code yields per-frame rescaling.

Comment: Yeah I want it per column. How should I rewrite it?

Comment: try the `axis` parameter.